# Creating a uniform container for images and text in Css

Tags: html, css

For the life of me, You know when you can not figure out what has gone awry with making a simple container, and passing what seems to be the right commands but isn't producing the right effect. I have tested that my external styles sheet is linked. I have float the text right left and changed it in different variations tested clearing, as well as the overflow is hidden and most other things regarding, alignment because the aim is responsive margins with 17% are being used. The Image is being floated left, as follows is the current structure in Html and Css in Classic Cascade style. I am attempting to have the text float on the right side of the image where the height would match the image`

```css
'/*CSS Snippit */
 .leadercard {
  margin-top: 10%;
  /* Add shadows to create the "card" effect */
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
}


/* On mouse-over, add a deeper shadow */

.leadercard:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/* Add some padding inside the card container */

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.leadercard {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* 5px rounded corners */
}


/* Add rounded corners to the top left and the top right corner of the image */

.leadercard>img {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}


/* This was used in the p tages as well */

.assetp {
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
}

.assetdiv>p {
  align: right;
}


/* End of "This was used in the p tages as well" */

#parentAssetBox {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class=".leadercard #parentAssetBox">
  <div class=".leadercard .container assetdiv">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/18/17/42/image-1465348_1280.jpg">
    <p> comprehensive overview of merchants current finance options</p>

    <p>Free email campaigns that we send to your customers monthly with your branding and promotions</p>

    <p>Negotiate special deals and terms with new and current finance companies</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your requirements are vague to me. Please provide more details.
Also remove the `.` as prefix from your class names in HTML.

Comment: Thank you that Probably would help something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please let me know, what you are trying to change in the example below, I just shrunk the image.
And removed `.` from your class name in your HTML.

### EDIT

As you can see here, I have added flex to your `.assetdiv`, which will allow your text to come next to image.

And your container will fit your image just like this
[image]

Now if you shrink the display, i.e try to make it responsive, your text height will force your outer container to expand. Like this
[image]

Well there is a way to hide that overflow as well. Like this
[image]

Let me if you are looking for the solution of the 3rd image else the current fix will work for you.

```css
'/*CSS Snippit */
 .leadercard {
  margin-top: 10%;
  /* Add shadows to create the "card" effect */
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
}


/* On mouse-over, add a deeper shadow */

.leadercard:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/* Add some padding inside the card container */

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.leadercard {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* 5px rounded corners */
}


/* Add rounded corners to the top left and the top right corner of the image */

.leadercard .inner >img {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  height: 200px;
}
/* This was used in the p tages as well */

.assetdiv>p {
  align: right;
}


/* End of "This was used in the p tages as well" */

#parentAssetBox {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.assetdiv{
  display:flex;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.para .par{
  overflow:hidden;
}

.para{overflow:hidden;
border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<div class="leadercard parentAssetBox">
  <div class="container assetdiv">
    <div class="inner">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/18/17/42/image-1465348_1280.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="inner para">
      <div class="par">
    <p> comprehensive overview of merchants current finance options</p>

    <p>Free email campaigns that we send to your customers monthly with your branding and promotions</p>

    <p>Negotiate special deals and terms with new and current finance companies</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am attempting to have the text float on the right side of the image where the height would match the image

Comment: Height of the Container or height of the text should be equal to the image?

Comment: The First example is exactly what I was hoping to achieve thank you for your help. I upvoted your effort and marked accordingly